# How to generate IDs for support tickets?

Tags: php

I am trying to generate support tickets for my website support option. I won't be using much features with the support system. I just want that the generated ticket ID numbers to not be repeated. What I tried gave me '0' two times in my database and single digits sometimes.

What I want is that whenever a new ticket is generated it should have consistent number of digits and never to repeat again.

The following is my code which I am using:

```
   $token = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
   $ticket = bin2hex($token);
```

Please guide me a better way.

Comment: Can't you just use a normal auto_increment?

Comment: You don't do that by using a random number. With a random you _obviously_ cannot make any predictions about the sequence. Instead you use the features builtin to the database. Either some `auto increment` like MySQL offer it or some key generator as used in other relational database systems.

Comment: @ayan Chill dude, you can easily do it without any coding in php. Just execute this mysql statement. `ALTER TABLE tokens AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;`

Comment: @Manikiran I feel this is better. Actually I had no clear conception of how tokens were generated

Comment: By the way can anyone tell me what was so bad in my question that it got 2 downvotes?

Comment: @Ayan there are some kind of questions, when giving too much information about a problem is harmful. If you'd ask how to generate a non-repeating pseudo-random sequence of numbers and could show an example of what you've done yourself, plus provided some links to similar questions - you could get some upvotes. *Disclaimer: I didn't vote* P.S.: Haters Gonna Hate

Comment: @Axalix, well haters didn't see that I did showed what I have done on my own. Anyway thanks for the insight about the downvotes.

Answer (score -2):

What kind of database are you using?

Use auto-increment to create unique ID's for your tickets. MySql has an item about his [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Thats not an answer, this is a comment.

Comment: am using mysql. I was looking for 6 digit numbers. What process do the ticket scripts follow?

Comment: @Ayan Other ticket scripts usually use auto_incremement as well.